# What do you do if you need 3 'tiers' of quotes?

Tags: php, html, css, quotes

For example, I know you can go from " to ' but is there a third?

I am making a $form variable and I need 3 levels of quotes

```
    $form = "<table id ='create_school_table'>
                    <tr>
                        <td>school name:</td>
                        <td><input type = 'text' maxlength='50' name='school_name' style='width: 174px;'/></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>state:</td>
                        <td><select name='state'>
                            <?php foreach ($states as $state) : ?>
                               //THIS NEXT LINE IS TRIPPING ME UP
                                <option value='<?php echo $state['state_name']; ?>'>
                                    <?php echo $state['state_name']; ?>
                                </option>
                            <?php endforeach; ?>
                    </select></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td></td>
                        <td><input type='button' value='add school' name='submitbtn' onclick='execute_add_school()' /></td> 
                    </tr>
                </table>"
```

Comment: Check this out: http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you use more variables?

```
$form = "Your initial HTML";

$states = "";
foreach ($states as $state) {
    $states .= "<option value='" . $state['state_name'] . "'>" 
            . $state['state_name'] . "</option>";
}

$form .= $states;
$form .= "the rest of your HTML";
```

If you are explicitly trying to keep it all in one variable, feel free to update your question to reflect that.

Comment: I guess the core of my answer is that while you could potentially use more than 2 layers of quotes, it might not be best practice. Getting to the point where you have 3 layers of quotations in a string indicates that your code is getting complex enough for you to try to simplify the logic in various other ways. Are you or someone else going to be OK with trying to visually cope with 3 layers of quotations when maintaining this code in the future?

Comment: I understand what you are saying but I think my logic is messed up because in a php page of an ajax request, I am coding html that has more php in it... I'm not sure if this makes sense

Comment: Do you mean you are sending this string as an ajax response?

Comment: ahhhhh nvm, this post makes so much sense and makes me so happy, thank you so much, reading this was like a revelation

Comment: No problem, friendo. Best of luck out there

Answer (score 0):

You can rewrite your code for clarity.

Assign blocks of html or processes results to variables and concatenate them wherever you need them.

Answer (score 0):

It is not quite clear what you are doing.

```
To escape quotes, use \"
To escape escaped quotes, use \\\"
etc.
```

However, it seems to me that you want the current value of the variable. You cannot "echo" into a variable, "echo" is for output. See fettereddingoskidney's answer for that.